# Kubelet Rootfs.UsedBytes missing in /stats/summary in Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubelet, kubernetes-metrics

We are consuming kubelet `/stats/summary` endpoint.

We noticed that the metrics returned are not always present and might be missing in some scenarios.

In particular we are interested in `Rootfs.UsedBytes` that in missing in `minikube` but present in other environments.

Command to retrieve `/stats/summary` from kubelet, notice that the port can vary in different k8s flavours

```
token=$(k get secrets <service-account-token-with-enough-privileges> -o json \
| jq .data.token -r | base64 -d -)

k run curler --rm -i --restart=Never --image nginx -- \
curl -X GET https://<nodeIP>:10250/stats/summary --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" --insecure
```

```
"pods": [
{
...
   "containers": [
   {
   ...
      "rootfs": {
         ...
         "usedBytes": 36864,
         ...
       }
```

- Why is that?
- Is there a similar metric more reliable?
- Can add anything in Minikube to enable that?

EDIT:

> It is possible that the issue is related to --driver=docker option of minikube

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster?

Comment: The cluster is a classical minikube, run with "minikube start" on OSX over Docker. Version 1.22. :)

Comment: Sorry for long response. I've analyzed your problem, but there are some understatement. Could you elaborate this sentence `"We noticed that the metrics returned are not always present and might be missing in some scenarios."` - what scenarios? If there are no metrics, does it work OK - are the pods to the cluster working?

Comment: For example they are missing in minikube when the driver is Docker on OSx. The cluster, however, seems perfectly fine and a "normal" user would not notice any difference in its operations.

Comment: Changing the driver to "Hyperkit" fixes the issue and that specific metric is available again under kubelet's /stats/summary

Answer (score 1):

To clarify I am posing community wiki answer.

The problem here was resolved by changing driver to ***Hyperkit***.

According to the [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperkit/):

> [HyperKit](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit)  is an open-source hypervisor for macOS hypervisor, optimized for lightweight virtual machines and container deployment.

There are two ways to install HyperKit (if you have installed Docker for Desktop, you don't need to do anything - you already have HyperKit):

- you can [install HyperKit from GitHub](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit)
- if you have [Brew Package Manager](https://brew.sh/) - run the following command:

```sh
brew install hyperkit
```

See also [this reference](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit).